Approximation to the differential equation $\dfrac{d^2\psi}{d \xi^2} = \xi^2 \psi$ for large values of $\xi$
I'm interested in understanding the approximate solution for large values of $\xi$ (as $\xi \rightarrow \infty$) of the following differential equation
$$\dfrac{d^2\psi}{d \xi^2} = \xi^2 \psi$$
which is an approximation to the QHO differential equation.
Now Griffiths states that the approximate solution is
$$\psi (\xi) = Ae^{-\xi^2/2} + Be^{\xi^2/2}$$
But if I differentiate this function twice I get
$$\dfrac{d^2\psi}{d \xi^2} = Be^{\xi^2/2} - Ae^{-\xi^2/2} + \xi^2 \psi$$
Now assuming $\xi$ is large the second term $- Ae^{-\xi^2/2} \rightarrow 0$ but the first term diverges.
So I don't get why that $\psi$ is the approximate solution.
If $\psi$ were
$$\psi (\xi) = Ae^{-\xi^2/2}$$
Then
$$\dfrac{d^2\psi}{d \xi^2} = - Ae^{-\xi^2/2} + \xi^2 \psi$$
And for large values of $\xi$ it is approximately
$$\dfrac{d^2\psi}{d \xi^2} = \xi^2 \psi$$
which satisfies that equation.
Am I wrong?
I mean Griffiths says that the first term is not physically acceptable but I claim that it's not even mathematically acceptable. The books says that the $\psi$ with the $B$ term is an approximate solution.

Isnt it just asserting that, in the absence of boundary conditions, the solution with A and B is approximately the solution of the offending ODE, and of course, if you have boundary at infinity, then only A will be tolerable? Why did you not write that the A-only solution gives you $$\psi^{\prime\prime}=(\xi^2-1)\psi$$ and that obviously, as $|\xi|\to\infty$, the -1 can be dropped and thus the solution is indeed approximately correct?

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Hint: if you let $A,,B$ depend on $\xi$ but assume they don't vary too fast when $\xi$ is large, you can use iterative approximations to work out higher-order corrections. The exact result is expressible in terms of the parabolic cylinder functions $D_{-1/2}(\sqrt{2}x),,D_{-1/2}(i\sqrt{2}x)$, expanded here. See if you can match that.

Thanks I've never heard of these cylinder functions.... Thanks!!!

Yes I mean I said that (the first comment) in a slightly different way... But I meant just what you said... I'm just asking why the first solution with the $B$ term is said to be an approximate solution if it diverges. I mean, it is clearly not a solutions.

If you let $B$ vary, it gives rise to a solution that diverges as $\xi\to\infty$, which is physically problematic, whereas $A$ doesn't have the same problem.

Actually, taking
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{d\xi^2}\left(A e^{-\xi^2/2} + B e^{\xi^2/2}\right)&= A e^{-\xi^2/2}(\xi^2-1) + B e^{\xi^2/2}(\xi^2+1) \\
& = \xi^2 \left(A e^{-\xi^2/2} + B e^{\xi^2/2}\right) - A e^{-\xi^2/2} + B e^{\xi^2/2}
\end{align}
so clearly the term with $\xi^2 \left(A e^{-\xi^2/2} + B e^{\xi^2/2}\right) $ dominates the other terms because of the extra $\xi^2$ prefactor.
Moreover, since the wavefunction must be $0$ at $\pm \infty$, you should remove the $e^{+\xi^2/2}$ by hand.

Alright!!!! Thanks!!! Yes of course there is the extra factor of $\xi^2$!!! Thank you sooooo much!!!
